# What is the current supply of wownero as of 2018-08-01

Tags: mining, emission-curve, wownero

What is the current supply of wownero and mining reward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As of 2018-08-01**, circulating supply is around 6 million out of a total of about 184 million, which will be emitted over the course of 50 years with no tail emission after depletion.

[image: Wownero emission]

The block reward is about 170 WOW.

Comment: just wow wow wow!