# What's Wownero's mining emission curve?

Tags: monero-forks, emission-curve, tail-emission, wownero

I tried searching for Wownero's emission schedule, but only found mining profit calculators and [this question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/9913/what-is-the-current-supply-of-wownero-as-of-2018-08-01) here, but it doesn't have any hard numbers.

Is there an equation or equivalent to [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qXi7zUSIh7F6UuSuhOryyFbHEy_LJuym3I3neAga_2s/edit#gid=239466694) Google sheet for Monero on Wownero's mining emission?

Answer (score 2):

You can see the emission curve here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsRLv.png

It's essentially the same exponential decay as Monero, but stretched out over 50 years or so rather than 7 or 8 years for Monero. Also note that there is no tail emission.

It is calculated from the source code. You can get the function here:  https://github.com/wownero/wownero/blob/4c6c7ab87b2a56165f400f6e49f17b9577a2bcad/src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_basic_impl.cpp#L84  and you can get the params to plug into the function in here: https://github.com/wownero/wownero/blob/master/src/cryptonote_config.h

Comment: I saw that graph (it's one of them linked in the question), but I'm wondering if there's a more accurate/precise one floating around.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that. It is calculated from the source code. You can get the function here:  https://github.com/wownero/wownero/blob/4c6c7ab87b2a56165f400f6e49f17b9577a2bcad/src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_basic_impl.cpp#L84  and you can get the params to plug into the function in here: https://github.com/wownero/wownero/blob/master/src/cryptonote_config.h